# Sandboxed operating system

Tags: security, operating-system, sandbox

On most operating systems today, the default is that when we install a program, it is given access to many resources that it may not need, and it's user may not intend to give it access to. For example, when one installs a closed source program, in principle there is nothing to stop it from reading the private keys in `~/.ssh` and send them to a malicious third party over the internet, and unless the user is a security expert proficient in using tracing programs, he will likely not be able to detect such a breach.

With the proliferation of many closed sourced programs being installed on computers, what actions are different operating systems taking to solve the problem of sandboxing third party programs?

Are there any operating system designed from the grounds up with security in mind, where every program or executable has to declare in a clearly readable format by the user what resources it requires to run, so that the OS runs it in a sandbox where it has access only to those resources? For example, an executable will have to declare that it will require access to a certain directory or a file on the filesystem, that it will have to reach certain domains or IP address over the network, that it will require certain amount of memory, etc ... If the executable lies in its declaration for system resource requirements, it should be prevented from accessing them by the operating system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a the beauty of Virtualization. Anyone performing testing or operating a questionable application would be wise to use a virtual machine.

Virtual Machines:

- Provide advantages of a full Operating System without direct hardware access
- Can crash or fail and be restarted without affecting the host machine
- Are cheap to deploy and configure to a variety of environments
- Great for using applications designed for other platforms
- Sandboxes applications that may attempt to access other private data on your computer

With the seamless modes virtualization programs such as VirtualBox provide you can take advantage of Virtual Machine's sandboxing in a nearly seamless fashion.

Comment: Qubes (http://qubes-os.org/Architecture.html) is a project that uses virtual machines to implement separate domains. In certain ways, this is a rediscovery/reimplementation of MAC using virtualization as a building block.

Comment: Virtualization has a big overhead of having to install a separate OS for each application. It would be more efficient to have a single OS with mandatory access control, which sandboxes each application.

Comment: Yes, I do agree virtualization for every application is a huge waste of overhead. As mentioned, this is the compromise of Mandatory Access Control. However, if you need a modern operating system to run the app in question, a single virtualization instance for a couple applications is easy to setup and manage by a user.

Answer (score 2):

You have just described MAC (Mandatory Access Control) in your last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

I was always curious about that too.

Nowadays mobile OSes like Android do have sandboxing built-in. When installing an app, it asks for permissions to access a set of resources/features. Windows too as far as I know, at least to some extend. It is more permissive though.

Ironically, linux and others seem to be far far away concerning "software based permissions" and are stuck in the past, which is a pity. *...at least, as far as I know. I would be pleased for someone to show me wrong and show me a "usable" open source system where application sandboxing/privileges is built-in. Currently, as far as I know, permissions are solely user based.*

I think this awareness that not only users need rights to access documents but also executables need rights to access resources has been missing for several decades. It might have avoided a plague of viruses and security issues of our century.